# How to format discrete events into a state-timeline compatible table?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to use Grafana's [state timeline graf](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/state-timeline/) and for this to work I need to transform my source data:

| TimeGenerated | playbook_name | status | runtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11:02 | config_backup | success | 3600 |
| 12:33 | update_inventory | success | 52 |
| 13:04 | config_backup | partial_success | 3600 |
| 14:31 | update_inventory | success | 47 |

Into this: (see below)

I want the job column to illustrate the status for as long as "job start time " + "runtime" is within the TimeGenerated column. Does that make sense?

Like, if the config_backup job starts at 11:00 and lasts for 3600 seconds, every row in the config_backup column between 11:00 and 12:00 should be marked, ultimately with the status of the "status" column, but I'm willing to compromise.

| TimeGenerated | config_backup | update_inventory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11:00 | success |  |
| 11:15 | success |  |
| 11:30 | success |  |
| 11:45 | success |  |
| 12:00 |  |  |
| 12:15 |  |  |
| 12:30 |  | success |
| 12:45 |  |  |
| 13:00 | partial_success |  |
| 13:15 | partial_success |  |
| 13:30 | partial_success |  |
| so on... |  |  |

There are a few steps involved here and I got fairly far but now I'm getting stuck so I need help.

First, we need to re-write the TimeGenerated into 15 minute blocks. This is how I've achieved it:

```
let _start=ago(1d);
let _end=now();
let interval = 15m;
let timetable = range TimeGenerated from ago(1d) to now() step 15m;
log_ansible_playbook_stats_CL
| union timetable
```

I also know how to use make_series to pivot the rows and columns, so for now I was focusing more on marking the status for as long as there is runtime left.

This is what I came up with

```
| extend runtime_s = toint(prev(runtime_s)) - 900
```

Thinking that, I can later do an extend case "if runtime is not empty, status = something"

The problem is, this only works for one row:

| TimeGenerated | playbook_name | status | runtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11:00 | config_backup | success | 3600 |
| 11:15 |  |  | 2700 |
| 11:30 |  |  |  |
| 11:45 |  |  |  |

And that's when I realized, the whole table is evaluated at once, not row-by-row as I was hoping. Now, I really don't know how to proceed. I've looked at the fillforward() function but it doesn't have a conditional so I can't stop it once we're outside the runtime of the job.

However, now that I say this I'm thinking I could emit a log at the START of the job, as well as at the END, then use fillforward() to fill the gap between the two timestamps.

But perhaps, I'm hoping that I simply missed the obvious solution and one of you can set me on the right path.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator to generate the additional time entries:

```
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime,playbook_name:string,status:string,runtime:int 
)[
datetime(11:02), "config_backup", "success", 3600,
datetime(12:33), "update_inventory", "success", 52,
datetime(13:04), "config_backup", "partial_success", 3600,
datetime(14:31), "update_inventory", "success", 47,
]
| mv-expand TimeGenerated=
    range(bin(TimeGenerated, 15m), TimeGenerated + runtime * 1s, 15m)
| project TimeGenerated, playbook_name, status
```

With mv-apply you can also generate time events with an empty status:

```
datatable (
    TimeGenerated: datetime,
    playbook_name: string,
    status: string,
    runtime: int
)[
    datetime(11:02), "config_backup", "success", 3600,
    datetime(12:33), "update_inventory", "success", 52,
    datetime(13:04), "config_backup", "partial_success", 3600,
    datetime(14:31), "update_inventory", "success", 47,
]
| mv-apply TimeGenerated2= range(datetime(11:00), datetime(15:00), 15m) to typeof(datetime) on (
  extend status= iff(TimeGenerated2 between (bin(TimeGenerated, 15m) .. (TimeGenerated + runtime * 1s)), status, "")
)
| project TimeGenerated= TimeGenerated2, playbook_name, status
| evaluate pivot(playbook_name, take_any(status))
```

Comment: That's great, it's bringing me to the finish line! The last thing I need is to generate 15 minute buckets even when there is nothing happening with either playbooks. I tried my previous timetable union trick but things are not going as planned: [See this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/pjXXw2r)

I'm using Grafana's Transform features to pivot my table.

You can see gaps between the "success" rows because these rows come from the timetable. I thought about using series_fill_forward() but it doesn't solve the issue of filling these gaps.

Comment: I'm not sure if I forgot how to read or if you added that second query but this second one really nails the solution. Thank you so much. You're using operations I've never seen in Kusto and so I feel I would have never figured this out. [Here is what it looks like, now.](https://imgur.com/a/v1iR7uk). I'm not trying to be greedy but if I may ask one more question. Notice the popup in the screenshot, it says update_inventory ran for 15 minutes. In reality it was 47 seconds. I understand it looks like this because of the query. Is there a way to fix that or is it a limit in KQL?